# C# Regex Phone Number Check Accepts Only xxx-xxx-xxxx

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following phone numbers and I need a regex that validate only numbers with format **xxx-xxx-xxxx**

```
281-388-0388   OK
281 388 0388   NO OK
(281)-388-0388 NO OK
(281)-388-0388 NO OK
```

I have this regex `\(?\d{3}\)?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4}` but all the above four number will be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply the following:

```
^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$
```

Comment: `\d` matches more than [0-9] in most modern regex engines.

Answer (score 0):

You want this as a regex `^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$`

Comment: I have to update to ^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$

Comment: Fixed answer as suggested